# Cronjob every 5 minutes

Tags: linux, cron, debian

I would like to know how to make a cronjob every 5 minutes ?

I found on Internet that I have to do `*/5 * * * *` but the problem is when I try this I am facing this error

[image: Sreenshort]

Where is the problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please show the full crontab file. The line snippet you have shown looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

It can be several things:

- there are an unwanted control characters in file (you can check with `cat -v /etc/crontab` or `cat -v /var/spool/cron/crontabs/username` if this is user crontab entry). Cron daemon has very sensitive parser and unwanted non-printable characters cause errors.
- there are empty variable assignments above/under the line erroring (such as `MAILTO=`)
- this is the last line in file and it does not end with newline character. Some implementations of cron (you don't state anything beyond "Debian" tag) require first and last line to NOT be crontab entries.
- you have very old cron implementation that doesn't support such `*/n` syntax (afaik Solaris and older busybox cron daemons don't). In that case you need to use workaround and list all 5 minute milestones within one hour like this  `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * command` as a workaround.

It would help if you post a minimal reproducible example of crontab file that errors and version of cron daemon you are using.